# Wrong codecoverage xml generation

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2015, code-coverage, tfsbuild

I have problem with VisualStudio CodeCoverage tool. I produce codecoverage file during Visual Studio Test task on build server. Than I have Sonar runner task and within these task *.codecoverage was converted to *.codecoveragexml. And these produce wrong XML. In XML there is reference to none existing line in one file. Wrong is reference to line 21 when file has 10 lines. And Sonnar has problem with this and crash when analyzing these file.

Can somebody know how to generate correct XML?

Thanks

File Content

```cs
using System;
using SomeOtherNamespace;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
  public class OrderChangedEventHandlerArgs : EventArgs
  {
    public OrderInfo Order { get; set; }
  }
}
```

```xml
<function id="64864" token="0x60003c5" name="get_Order()" type_name="OrderChangedEventHandlerArgs" block_coverage="100.00" line_coverage="100.00" blocks_covered="1" blocks_not_covered="0" lines_covered="2" lines_partially_covered="0" lines_not_covered="0">
  <ranges>
    <range source_id="67" covered="yes" start_line="8" start_column="30" end_line="8" end_column="34" />
    <range source_id="67" covered="yes" start_line="8" start_column="35" end_line="8" end_column="39" />
    <range source_id="67" covered="yes" start_line="21" start_column="5" end_line="21" end_column="51" />
  </ranges>
</function>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check instructions on the page below to get Visual Studio code coverage imported in SonarQube: http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/CoBh

.NET Code Coverage is imported into SonarQube in 4 steps:

1. Run the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin command, specifying the absolute path where the code coverage report will be available using the `/d:propertyKey=path` syntax ("propertyKey" depends on the code coverage tool)
2. Build your project using MSBuild
3. Run your code coverage tool, instructing it to produce a report at the same location specified earlier to the MSBuild SonarQube Runner
4. Run the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end command

Comment: I know it but originally it's not called by me but by Agent from TFS 2015 Update 1 OnPremise. I add task for Sonar to two of my projects in one all works great but in second I get error from Sonar runner about  processing codecoverage with more lines than file have.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add blank lines to end of file and make file as long as error says. It's not best solution but it works for me.